# Backup and restore file-based encryption keys

Tags: backup, encryption

[Android File-Based Encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based) is implemented via [fscrypt](https://github.com/google/fscrypt). How do you backup and restore fscrypt encryption keys? Both the master keys and the per-file keys would need to be backed up.

Comment: From your first link *1.Keymaster/Keystore and Gatekeeper must be implemented in a Trusted Execution Environment 2.Hardware Root of Trust and Verified Boot bound to the keymaster initialisation is required to ensure that Device Encryption credentials are not accessible by an unauthorized operating system* // TEE is something that cannot be accessed directly and calls to TEE information are severely restricted ( I am not technical enough to elaborate on this ) and it's virtually impossible to get information from TEE // So, IMO, you can't

Comment: Master keys are stored by TEE. You cannot clone them. Some key material that is used with master keys can be found in `/data/system`. As long as you are not doing factory reset or wiping `/data` through TWRP & reinitializing the OS, TEE will not flush master keys.