# How to "unwipe" internal storage in TWRP Recovery

Tags: internal-storage, twrp

I accidentally wiped the internal storage of my phone in TWRP Recovery, it contains **extremely** important data and I need it back asap. The phone has been shut down if it helps, thanks!

Edit - Just before wiping (everything in twrp format section) I made a full nandroid backup (*excluding* Internal Storage), would that help with recovery?

Comment: Unless your device is pretty old user data partition is encrypted by default. Clearing it means you have also erased the necessary encryption keys which makes recovery impossible. See also comments on this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/237471/backup-and-restore-file-based-encryption-keys

Comment: in case userdata is ext4 file system *'adb pull /dev/block/dm-0'* to PC (from TWRP) and try testdisk or extundelete (on PC)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull data from internal memory on an unrooted phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219346/how-to-pull-data-from-internal-memory-on-an-unrooted-phone)

Comment: no, backup excluding /data/media is useless for recovering /data/media. what is encryption type (FDE/FBE/none)? what is file system type (ext4/f2fs)?